# androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView setSearchableInfo() throws Resources$NotFoundException on some devices

Tags: java, android, androidx

I noticed several exceptions on report logs and i have no idea what the reason of issue:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.Resources.getText (Resources.java:363)
  at android.content.Context.getText (Context.java:567)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.getQueryHint (SearchView.java:622)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.updateQueryHint (SearchView.java:1102)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo (SearchView.java:409)
  at com.myApp.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu (MainActivity.java:161)
  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu (Activity.java:3575)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu (FragmentActivity.java:325)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2830)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu (ToolbarActionBar.java:455)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run (ToolbarActionBar.java:56)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:949)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:761)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:693)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:935)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7094)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        mainMenu = menu;
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        if(searchManager != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

`R.menu.main_activity_actions.xml` looks like

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

The devices that throws exceptions is **Samsung Galaxy J6+ (Android 9)**, **Xiaomi Redmi 6A (Android 9)**

I dont know which solution is correct, because i tried to repeat this issue, but not able to do it. This exceptions throwed rarely. It started after migration to AndroidX

Comment: the same problem here, if you found a solution please write it

Answer (score 0):

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/search_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title="@string/search_text"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
```

androidx   `app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"`

Comment: Mind explaining why your answer will solve the problem?